How do I redirect the default wordpress search results url to a custom slug
I'm trying to prepend /team to the search results page in wordpress. Currently my form has the correct action and goes to the correct url on search but the page is 404ing.
<form class="team-wrapper__search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url('/team/'); ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="search-type" value="team">
  <input type="text" name="s" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" placeholder="Search for a specialist" required="required">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

If I go to domainname.com/?search-type=team&s=adam  the search results are displayed correctly. But I need to make it so that the results display in domainname.com/team/?search-type=team&s=adam. As of now this page hits a 404.
The client has also installed a plugin called Ajax search pro but unsure how relevant this is to the question.
